# Colored word with listings

Tags: listings, color, python

I added to the list of keywords by the colorful package listings (python) some functions of scipy.signal library using the otherkeywords control, I added the lti order, this order is put in color but  the problem is that the text "lti" is also colored in the word "multi".

- How to avoid this side effect?
- Is it possible to add all the keywords of a library (matplolib for example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used `morekeywords` option instead of `otherkeywords` and you probably was loading the default predifined language by specifying `\begin{lstlisting}[style=Python]`, as a first step you should define your listings language style (customize) by `lstdefinestyle` and then use it in the `lstlisting` environment as a style `style=myPython`.

For the second part i am not sure but i am afraid there is no other way to add keywords automatically rather than adding them by collecting, the list of the library keywords and pasting it into `morekeywords = {keyword1,...}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{textcomp} %for upquote

\definecolor{keywords}{rgb}{0,0,0.7}

\lstdefinestyle{myPython} {
    language=Python,
    keywordstyle=*\color{keywords},
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\scriptsize,
    commentstyle=*\color{green!50},
    stepnumber=1,
    numbersep=8pt,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines=true,
    frameround=ftff,
    frame=lines,
    morekeywords = {lti},
    backgroundcolor=\color{gray!20},
    firstnumber=1,
    upquote=true  %for straight single quotes
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=myPython]
def greet(name):
    print 'Hello', name
greet('LaTeX')
multi lti
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]