# Adding `otherkeywords` in listings - How do I avoid highlighting them inside strings?

Tags: listings

I'm using the `listings` package for Python code, and I have set

```
otherkeywords={self,__init__}
```

An unintended side-effect of this seems to be that in a string such as

```
"self_loathing"
```

the `self` portion is highlighted as a keyword while the rest gets string highlighting. Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, following the lead of [Colored word with listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318566/colored-word-with-listings), I used `morekeywords` instead of `otherkeywords`, to describe `self`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{main-color}{rgb}{0.6627, 0.7176, 0.7764}
\definecolor{back-color}{rgb}{0.1686, 0.1686, 0.1686}
\definecolor{string-color}{rgb}{0.3333, 0.5254, 0.345}
\definecolor{key-color}{rgb}{0.8, 0.47, 0.196}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}
{
    language = C++,
    basicstyle = {\ttfamily \color{main-color}},
    backgroundcolor = {\color{back-color}},
    stringstyle = {\color{string-color}},
    otherkeywords = {;},
    morekeywords = {self},
    keywordstyle = {\color{key-color}},
    alsoletter = {_},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style = mystyle]
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int x = 2;

//comment
for (self = 0; self < x; ++self) {
    cout << "self_loathing" << endl;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If I add `self` to `otherkeywords` instead of `morekeywords`, I get the problem described by the OP:

[image]