# Adding similar operators to listings

Tags: listings

I'm trying to create a new language definition with operators `=>` and `>`.

Highlighting both `=>` and `>` doesn't seem to work.

I have tried putting them in `otherkeywords` in both orders. Neither seem to work.

In the code below, only the `>` is highlighted. Is it possible to get them both highlighting?

Thanks

```
\documentclass[a4]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\definecolor{backcolour}{RGB}{242,242,0235}
\definecolor{codegray}{RGB}{128,128,128}
\definecolor{codeOrange}{RGB}{254, 97, 0}
\definecolor{codeBlue}{RGB}{100, 143, 255}

\lstdefinestyle{newStyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{codeBlue},
    keywordstyle=[0]\color{codeBlue},
    keywordstyle=[1]\color{codeBlue},
    keywordstyle=[2]\color{codeBlue},
    keywordstyle=[3]\color{codeBlue},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codeOrange},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                                                 
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=4
}

\lstdefinelanguage{newLanguage}{
    keywords={type,def,True,False},
    otherkeywords={!,\$,|,<,[,],::,=>,>},
    otherkeywords={>},
    sensitive=true,
    morecomment=[l]{//},
    morecomment=[n]{/*}{*/},
    morestring=[b]",
    morestring=[b]"""
}


\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=newLanguage,style=newStyle]
a = [1,>,2]
b => c
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Support for the `otherkeywords` option is "a bit buggy" at the moment if the same character occurs in different keywords (see also [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/489856/proper-usage-of-otherkeywords-option-in-listings)).

You can check the behavior for different keyword lists:

```
otherkeywords={!,\$,|,<,[,],::,>}
```

[image]

```
otherkeywords={!,\$,|,<,[,],::,=>}
```

[image]

Those are correct. But as soon as you add both, things go wrong:

```
otherkeywords={!,\$,|,<,[,],::,=>,>}
```

[image]

As a workaround you could use the `literate` option to set the style for all literate occurrences of `=>` explicitly:

```
otherkeywords={!,\$,|,<,[,],::,>},
literate={=>}{{\textcolor{codeBlue}{=}}{\textcolor{codeBlue}{>}}}{2}
```

[image]

The drawback of this approach is that `=>` will be replaced in all places, so operators like `==>` will be apprear incorrect.