# Listings morekeywors is no adding special caracters like ::, + etc

Tags: listings

when i use morekeys in the lstdefinestyle it succesfully adds any word but it doesn't work with some characters like +,<, etc.

this is the style:

```
\lstdefinestyle{ligth}{
morekeywords = [1]{},
keywordstyle = [1]\color{red},
morekeywords = [2]{otherwise,\_, |, >, ==, :: },
keywordstyle = [2]\color{blue}}
```

This adds perfectly fine the word otherwise and _ but it doesn't add any of the others: , >,==,::
How can I fix this?? Thanks for your time

Comment: Hey Pablo, welcome to TeX.SE! It would be helpful if you could post a short example code that shows the issue you're referring to, but also so that we have some quick code to copy and paste in our machines instead of having to write it from scratch. Thanks!

Comment: From the duplicate: for keywords containing symbols you need `otherkeywords` instead of `morekeywords`.

Comment: Also related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/489856/proper-usage-of-otherkeywords-option-in-listings

Comment: Thanks for the answers Alenanno and Marijin :)